# Want to know if one can simplify this SQL query further to determine highest stackoverflow post on the last date of dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Looking over BigQuery's stackoverflow public dataset and my goal is to query the highest scored posts on the latest day of dataset. Want to print the date, score, view count, user name, etc.

```
SELECT display_name name, score, view_count, title, date 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` as u  
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT owner_user_id, date(creation_date) date, view_count, score, title 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts`
  WHERE date(creation_date) = (
    SELECT max(date(creation_date))
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts`
      )
  ) as p
  ON u.id = p.owner_user_id 
WHERE view_count IS NOT NULL and owner_user_id IS NOT NULL and title IS 
NOT NULL
ORDER by score DESC
LIMIT 50
```

While this works, it does require me to use 2 subqueries. I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this using just a join.

I find my first obstacle is being unable to use the max() function anywhere outside of SELECT and it can only be used with other aggregated columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this using just a join.

You query is already good enough performance and readability wise, but if you wish to use JOIN instead of WHERE - below version should produce same result and be slightly faster

```
#standardSQL
SELECT display_name name, score, view_count, title, DATE 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` AS u  
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT owner_user_id, DATE(creation_date) DATE, view_count, score, title 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts` a
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(DATE(creation_date)) max_date
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts`
  ) b
  ON DATE(creation_date) = max_date
  WHERE view_count IS NOT NULL AND owner_user_id IS NOT NULL AND title IS NOT NULL
) AS p
ON u.id = p.owner_user_id 
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Note: there are two adjustments

- Most inner WHERE transformed into JOIN
- Most outer WHERE moved inside

Answer (score 1):

You need a query to select the columns you want, and a query to get the latest day which is a minimum of two subqueries if you're not counting `JOIN`s as queries.

I think what you have is going to be essentially equivalent to if not better than other options. The 2nd nested query to get the latest date will be cached, it will not re-execute that for each row in the outer query. Compared to hardcoding the latest date instead of looking it up on the fly, there is no notable runtime or read size difference.

You can sort of 'flatten' the query by using `WITH` to construct a resultset of the filter values first and then `INNER JOIN` them with the original outer queries, which behaves like a `WHERE` clause. For this specific case I don't see any improvement in runtime or data read size when doing this. It is also a bit less readable in my personal opinion. Depending on the tables you're joining, using the `JOIN` method instead of filtering before the join might result in slower queries because it has to read more data, I'm not entirely sure how BigQuery handles that.

```
WITH max_creation_date as (
  SELECT max(date(creation_date)) as date
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts`)
SELECT display_name name, score, view_count, title, date(p.creation_date) as date
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` as u  
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts` as p
  ON u.id = p.owner_user_id
INNER JOIN max_creation_date
  ON max_creation_date.date = date(p.creation_date)
WHERE view_count IS NOT NULL 
  AND owner_user_id IS NOT NULL 
  AND title IS NOT NULL
ORDER by score DESC
LIMIT 50
```

You could technically turn the other 3 `WHERE` clauses into `INNER JOIN` clauses as well but that would probably be less readable and potentially slower than what you have.